# How to make laravel load all classes from a directory?

Tags: laravel-4

In my laravel app, i have a controller that does the following before the definition of the controller:

```
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Address;
```

Simply put, How can i make all the models in the API directory to be used?

Comment: You can use `Paypal\Api`, then in the code `Api\Payer` etc, nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the `PayPal\Api` namespace.

```
use PayPal\Api;
```

Then you can use the classes via `Api\Class`.

```
$payment = new Api\Payment;
```